# Bootstrap, 4.5.2 setting div's class as d-none d-sm-block to hide content on x small doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4, sigh... I am using this to hide the content for x small devices. It's simply ignored! why? It's showing in my smartphones. The resulution of the device is 720x1440 pixels. 5.45 inches.

```
  <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
          frustation is all around me!
  </div>
```

Comment: I just realized that my device is not x small! I am not ashamed to make this mistake. Of course my device is "x small" . Other libraries use words like "table", "desktop" and etc. Bootstrap was revolutionary but nowadays it lacks a lot in the way he sees things and also the lack of components.

Answer (score 0):

Extra small breakpoint has is <576px, and your device is above that breakpoint. See documentation here [bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers)